# Epimerization in peptide synthesis

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry

How can [epimerization](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/epimerization) during peptide synthesis be detected? And how can we change or modify the coupling conditions to stop epimerization occurring?

Answer (score 1):

The technique of Circular dichroism (CD) is used to detect changes and the presence of chirality in peptides and can detect both helical chirality in polypeptide chains that form helices and in individual chiral centers.

Polarimetry. The optical activity of a polypeptide (oligopeptide) has a specific rotation. A change in the optical rotation of such a peptide. Chirality is a property of a molecule as a whole. Such a change will alter the optical rotation of the peptide.